# Any ideas on how to prepare for the future of Flash/Flex/HTML5 Development?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, html, flash-builder

I've chosen Flex 4 as the most appropriate technology to develop a graphically-rich web application (its not a simple content-driven site), but worried about how the recent negative press (i.e. security issues) may effect end-user's trust and ultimately whether the user-base may drop promptly in response. (I don't care if my app works on iphones or ipads for now)

I think Flash Builder 4 is an great development environment and has minimized development time for me/my team. After some basic testing of graphical animations similar to that used in my app - HTML5 didn't perform as fast, is inconsistent with browsers, and some animations are jagged (I expect browser performance and graphic libraries to improve over time). I also 'personally' dislike programming Javascript as I am very fond of strong-typing to uncover mistakes quickly.

If you develop Rich Internet Apps, how are you responding?

Are you preparing to potentially migrate to HTML5/Javascript? Java? No action?

BTW - I don't want pro/anti-flash arguments - just curious to see how the community is responding.

Comment: You cannot expect to create internet apps for the modern web without javascript.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow ! When you say `just curious to see how the community is responding.`  means this should be marked as Community Wiki.

Comment: @Rob http://www.adobe.com/resources/business/rich_internet_apps/

Comment: @Rob I use plenty of modern Internet apps that don't use JavaScript.  iTunes, Skype, Trillian, and Tweetdeck to some I'm using right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of the day, Flash/Flex aren't going anywhere. If Flex 4 meets your current needs and you're aware of the limitations (ie can't deploy to iOS devices) then I say go for it. Yes it's true that the topic has become mildly politicized - but if you're offering something your clients need then they'd be silly to refuse to use it on the grounds that they support "HTML 5" - when HTML 5 clearly doesn't offer you the tools you need.

Plenty of awesome stuff is coming down the pipe in Flash, much of which simply can't be done any other way - google UJam for an example. I wouldn't let Steve Jobs scare you away from using the technology that works for your needs.

Comment: +1 for this. If Flash/Flex is the most productive for your team right now and you don't need to support iOS, then use it. The flash platform is not a sinking ship, at least not for a long time yet.

I personally have moved to writing web app GUIs in html/javascript, but only because I usually need the iOS compatibility.

Comment: Myk, I hope that by "Flash/Flex aren't going anywhere" you really mean "Flash/Flex aren't going away." :)

Comment: Haha, thanks for that, Robusto - you're right. I mean they're going to be around for a while. #AmbiguitySucks

Comment: Flex apps can be packaged to mobile since Flex 4.5.1 SDK.

Answer (score 2):

My company plans to continue with Flash, using FlashBuilder 4 and Java back end. We went with Flex/Flash several years ago to get out of the business of supporting all the different browsers and into the business of being productive and giving our users a rich client-side experience.

HTML5/Javascript have potential, but are nowhere near as robust, powerful, fast, or efficient. The class hierarchy, data typing, and event model alone put ActionScript 3 miles beyond any Javascript. So what if Steve Jobs gives Flash the thumbs down? Time-Warner and other big media companies have said they're going to continue with Flash, so it's only a matter of time before Steve Jobs either relegates Apple to permanent niche status or caves and allows Flash on Apple products. (My guess is for the immediate future he will prefer niche status to admitting he is wrong—look how long he maintained a mouse only needed a single button?—but that's just my opinion.) In any case, Flash will soon be available on a multitude of smart phones, including the Droid, so I am not worried.

Comment: Exactly. I don't use Flash for the sake of it but for what you mention: robust, powerful, fast, and efficient. If HTML5 was everything that Flash was then Flash would be gone already.

Answer (score 1):

Adobe will provide tools to convert to HTML5, but they are already following the HTML5 Path with some introductory tools.  Just keep watch on adobe.  They know what is going on.  They just killed mobile flash so even though they argued with apple over it they finally did the right thing instead of stupidly holding on to it just because...  hope that helps

Comment: Flash apps are packaged to mobile with AIR.  Adobe's statement was regarding Flash support in mobile browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a Flex developer, but I think HTML5 is going to be huge.  The full features of HTML5 are years away, and I don't think it's totally going to kill Flash.  Flex will hold on to some part of the RIA market because it has a lot more going for than just a de facto standard client plugin -- LCDS/BlazeDS, plays nicely with ColdFusion and Java.

I like Flex for the long run.  It'll lose some ground to HTML5, but there are areas where Flex will hold its advantage.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I am author of Web Atoms JS

Flex/Flash is dead already, as usage of non PC devices is increasing everyday. Except old IE (IE<10) almost all features of Flash are already offered by browsers. File API, AJAX upload with progress bar,Canvas API, Indexed DB, Cross Domain message API & Web Sockets. And CSS3, WebGL with 3D can give flash like graphics.

Regarding Component Library & Binding, HTML5+JS lacks component driven development that flash offers. To bridge this gap, we created framework that gives similar functionality with all components to that of flex. Look at following image & see this blog which outlines similarities between Flex & Web Atoms JS.

http://akashkava.com/blog/439/migrating-from-flex-to-html5-with-web-atoms-js/

Here is link to documentation.
http://webatomsjs.neurospeech.com/docs

[image: Flex to HTML]